# Can't print errno in gdb, complains about missing shared library, but it exists

Tags: ubuntu, gdb, shared-libraries, libc, errno

When debugging my application, if I break in GDB and try to print errno, even from inside a function that checks errno, I get the following error from GDB:

```
(gdb) print errno
Cannot find shared library `/usr/lib/debug/lib/libc-2.11.1.so' in dynamic linker's load module list
```

Things I've tried:

1. Check if the file exists, it does and is about 7.3MB.
2. Adding /usr/lib/debug/lib/ to the front of my LD_LIBRARY_PATH. No effect.
3. Setting LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/debug/lib/libc-2.11.1.so causes my app to segfault on startup.
4. If I run ldd on the binary it says it's using '/lib/libc.so.6', and aptitude (I'm running Ubuntu) tells me libc6-dbg *is* installed.
5. Checked that I don't have a custom lib path set in .gdbinit, I don't.

The application seems to otherwise run fine, so I can't imagine libc itself is screwed up. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like your shell start up files clobbering LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Check this link, [http://ipucu.enderunix.org/view.php?id=1720&lang=en]. Hope useful.

Comment: @SunEric: AFAICT, system paths like /usr/lib are always searched automatically. Also I pointed out in #2 that explicitly adding the path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH does not fix the error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The file `/usr/lib/debug/lib/libc-2.11.1.so` does *not* contain a debug version of glibc. It contains *only* debug parts of libc, but *no actual executable code*. Putting it into `LD_PRELOAD` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is the *wrong* thing to do. Do not do that.

You can read about separate debug files [here](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html).

> (gdb) print errno
>   Cannot find shared library `/usr/lib/debug/lib/libc-2.11.1.so' in dynamic linker's load module list

This is a buglet in GDB.

You should know that GDB will look for a variable `errno`, but your application does not use any such variable. Rather, `errno` is a `#define`d macro, that expands to `*(__errno_location())`, and GDB doesn't know about this.

Try this instead:

```
(gdb) p __errno_location()
$1 = (int *) 0x7ffff78396a8

(gdb) x/x $1
0x7ffff78396a8: 0x00000000
```